# probability a brownian motion is between two numbers

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

I'm studying for my probability final and the review has some questions on Brownian motion I don't understand. 
One is $P(1<B_1<3)$ for B a brownian motion.  Is this simply the probability that a standard normal distribution is between 1 and 3?
The second question is $P(B_e < B_3)$ which since both are centered at 0 I believe would simply be 1/2 by symmetry, but I'm having some trouble showing it formally.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, the first is exactly right.  The second is mostly right, but the reasoning is wrong.  Remember that $B_e$ and $B_3$ are not independent, so the reasoning that they're both centered at 0 and therefore the probability must be $1/2$ doesn't work.  Try rewriting it as the probability of a single normally distributed random variable.

Comment: The first is right because of property of Brownian motion. In particular, for any $0\leq s<t,$ $B_t-B_s\sim N(0, t-s).$ Since $B_0=0$, so $B_1 = B_1 - B_0 \sim N(0, 1).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first answer is correct. For the second question you can use the fact that a B.M. has stationary increments, so $B_t - B_s$ has the same distribution as $B_{t-s}.$ Without loss of generality we can assume $e<3.$ Then 
$$P(B_e < B_3) =P(B_e -B_e < B_3 - B_e) = P(B_0 < B_{3-e}) = P(0 < B_{3-e})= \frac{1}{2}.$$